# I want to hide label whenever something is typed in text box in aspx page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to hide label, whenever something is typed in text box in aspx page.

I am trying something like this :

```
protected void txt_LastName_KeyPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label_msg.Visible = false;
}
protected void txt_LastName_KeyDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label_msg.Visible = false;
}
```

But it is not happening. Do I need to write something like this in focus event?

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to use Javascript.

Comment: Even if you could do what you wanted to do, it would be a performance nightmare in client-server web world, as you would be posting back to the server on every key press! :-(

Comment: Set Textbox's AutoPostBack Property to true

Comment: @gypsyCoder: Insanity.

Comment: Javascript can help you on this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do some thing simple as below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function hideOnKeyPress() {
            document.getElementById('lblHidden').style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMaintCost" onkeypress="hideOnKeyPress(); return true;" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="lblHidden" runat="server" Text="I'll hide when you type something in the text box" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need javascript

Here is an implementation using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
<script>
    $('#txt_LastName').focus(function() {
        $('#Label_msg').hide();
    });
    $('#txt_LastName').blur(function() {
        $('#Label_msg').show();
    });
</script>
```

A plain vanilla javascript solution would be

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("txt_LastName").onfocus = function() {
        document.getElementById("Label_msg").style.display = 'none';
    };
    document.getElementById("txt_LastName").onblur = function() {
        document.getElementById("Label_msg").style.display = 'inherit';
    };
</script>
```

Comment: You might specify (given OP's lack of knowledge around this topic) that this is a jQuery solution. It might be helpful if you also provided the vanilla.js solution.

Answer (score 2):

This one may be helpful for you. Do as following...

Firstly, Set Textbox's AutoPostBack Property to true

```
AutoPostBack="True"
```

Then, Use OnTextChanged Event

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the visibility of a layer event based server side. You have to put this into a javascript procedure.

You have to possibilities: The easy way is, to use jQuery (you need to include jQuery!):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#txt_LastName').focus(function() {
        $('#Label_msg').hide();
    });
    $('#txt_LastName').blur(function() {
        $('#Label_msg').show();
    });
}
</script>
```

Second method: do it the hard way
If you don't want to use jQuery for some reason, you have to work directly with the DOM.
You can read about it there: [W3Schools DOM Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_methods.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into a JavaScript MVVM library, such as [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/), like this:

```
<p>Your value: <input data-bind="value: someValue, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></p>
<p>You have typed: <span data-bind="text: someValue"></span></p>

// Here's my data model
var viewModel = {
    someValue: ko.observable("edit me")
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/12100/) to illustrate how easy it is to achieve your desired key down functionality with JavaScript via KnockoutJS.

Answer (score 1):

a simple javascript solution would be

**HTML**

```
<span id="one">text</span>
<input type="text" onkeypress="hide()" />
```

**Javascript**

```
var isHidden = false;
function hide(){
  if(!isHidden){
   isHidden = true; 
   document.getElementById("one").setAttribute("style","display:none");
  }
}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iPUROKO/1/) demo

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no KeyPress Event in ASP.Net forms unlike Winforms you must use JQuery short hand code (for JavaScript) to handle hiding your label when user is typing in the textbox like this example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtUserName").keypress(function () {
            $("#lblUser").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```